# Using Python.NET in a C# Azure function

Tags: python, c#, azure-functions, python.net

We have developed all our functions using C#, and would like to continue doing so. But we have a parsing library written in Python that we'd like to use. We've therefor looked at `Python.NET` (pythonnet) to execute the Python code within our C# process.

Everything works if I run it locally using a vanilla C# Console app. But when I move the same code to a Azure function project it fails (even locally).

```cs
Runtime.PythonDLL = @"python310.dll";
PythonEngine.Initialize();

// This line fails with "No module named 'wmbus2json'"
var parser = Py.Import(@"wmbus2json");
```

It seams the runtime cannot find the Python files although they are in the *bin* directory.
We are running our Azure Function using **.net 6 Isolated**

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you considered simply creating another simple Azure Function using python natively and then just call that for the parsing from your .NET function. I feel like that might be a more robust and future-proof solution?

Comment: We have and are considering it, but we'd rather use Python.Net if it works

Answer (score 0):

The following works when running locally.

```
    Runtime.PythonDLL = @"python310.dll";
    PythonEngine.Initialize();
    using var _ = Py.GIL();
    string scriptPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "wmbus2json.py");
    dynamic sys = Py.Import("sys");
    sys.path.append(Path.GetDirectoryName(scriptPath));
    PyObject pythonLib = Py.Import(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(scriptPath));
```